# Hide single menu item from users without a specific role (without 3rd party module)

Tags: 7, routes, users

I have a menu and would like to hide a specific item if the currently authenticated users doesn't have the "editor" role, which i created.

Since this is such a small thing, i would like to achieve that without the use of a 3rd party module.

update::

This is not about security, I just want to hide the item regardless of the linked node's permission. In my specific case I'm even linking to a public node and just want to hide the menu item as long as the user hasn't the "editor" role.

Comment: How did you created menu? In drupal way or somthing else ?

Comment: just through the menu ui

Comment: Use css to hide it.. You can read user roles as classes..

Comment: @AnilSagar interesting!

Comment: If you created the Menu through Drupal Menu then it is only visible for the roles that have permission to view it. First check your permissions properly

Comment: @JhilkeDai Well the thing is that the item links to a public node. However, i would still like to hide it as long as the user doesn't have the "editor" role.

Comment: @n00b If the path is a node, use the node access system ([`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7)). Menu links will automatically fall in line using that method

Comment: Either you need to write a custom module or use contributed module... With out that you cannot achieve what you are trying to do using out of the box drupal core.. As clive said, You can hide the link but it's accessible if some one inputs directly into the browser..

Comment: @Clive The path is, but i want to make it independent from what type of content to display. It's just a matter to hiding the item.

Comment: Okee dokee - I've removed the "user-permissions" tag to avoid confusion, as this isn't about permissions

Comment: @Clive: Seems like all out attack on this question post.. Is this perfect time to close as "Too Broad" :-P ?

Comment: @AnilSagar Nah, looks good to me - different use case from the usual 'how do I hide this link' question, so should be useful

Answer (score 1):

Use [hook_menu_item_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item_link/6) to alter menu items. See below example:

```
function mytheme_menu_item_link( $link ) {
  if( $link[ 'title' ] == 'My Account') {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Or `return NULL` ;)

Answer (score 0):

If security is not that important. This should kinda do the trick (untested code).

```
function YourTheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#href'] == 'menu link to hide') {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'invisible';
  }

 return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me. I needed to replace `$variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'invisible'` with `return NULL`; That works.